# Best way to write html & Css separately in rails mailers. And combine both at the time of sending mails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the best way to write html & Css separately in rails mailers. And combine both at the time of sending mails.

Currently I am suing inline css. But I don't want to use inline css.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [premailer gem](https://github.com/premailer/premailer), it will do the job for you, and checkout example [here](https://hackernotes.io/a-production-ready-rails-5-email-workflow-with-mailer-previews-premailer-and-activejob/).

**Update**

Here is basic usage you can follow:

in your Gemfile, add premailer-rails with...

```
gem 'premailer-rails'
```

in app/assets/stylesheets/mailer.sass

```
body
  padding: 0
  background: #f7f7f7
  text-align: center

.email-table
  width: 538px
  padding: 20px
  background: #fff
  margin: 40px auto
  text-align: left
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'

h1
  font-size: 20px

p
  margin-top: 0
  font-size: 15px
```

add in config/initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( mailer.css )
```

in app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <!-- * simply referencing the stylesheet with this stylesheet_link_tag * -->
    <!-- * is enough for premailer to pull-in and inline your styles * -->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "mailer" %>

  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24143120)

Comment: @rickvdbosch you're right, I just updated the answer.